# Defining FieldNameConverter inside GraphQL.Types.Schema is not working in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql-dotnet

I am using **graphql-dotnet** and **graphql-dotnet server** with asp.net core.  I have configured schema in following way.

```
public class PdsGraphQlSchema: Schema
{
    public PdsGraphQlSchema()
    {
        FieldNameConverter = new PascalCaseFieldNameConverter();
        Query = CommonServiceLocator.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<GraphQlQueries>();
        Mutation = CommonServiceLocator.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<GraphQlMutations>();
    }
}
```

Here I have added `FieldNameConverter = new PascalCaseFieldNameConverter()`; but i am not getting the changes at output. Output always camelCased. How i can ignore camel casing or use Pascale casing.

For ConfigureServices I have used following

```
services.AddGraphQL(_ =>
            {
                _.EnableMetrics = true;
                _.ExposeExceptions = true;
            });
```

services.AddSingleton();

and inside `Configure` I have used following

```
app.UseGraphQL<PdsGraphQlSchema>();
app.UseGraphQLPlayground(new GraphQLPlaygroundOptions
{   Path = "/ui/playground" });
```

Expecting your help.

Answer (score 2):

you must use from NameConverter field in your schema

```
public class AppSchema : Schema
{
    public AppSchema(IServiceProvider provider)
        : base(provider)
    {
        NameConverter = new GraphQL.Conversion.DefaultNameConverter();
        Query = new AppQuery();
        Mutation = new AppMutation();
    }
}
```

you have 3 options

1- DefaultFieldNameConverter()  without Change,You see what you wrote in the output

2- PascalCaseFieldNameConverter()   in the all  First Charecter to Lowercase

3- CamelCaseFieldNameConverter()  in the all  First Charecter to Lowercase

Answer (score 1):

For this issue, it is caused by [DefaultGraphQLExecuter](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/server/blob/c8d2587d0106136fb09879d3b84a7143ddf282f7/src/Core/Internal/DefaultGraphQLExecuter.cs) did not set `FieldNameConverter` in `GetOptions`.

Try solutions below:

- Custom `DefaultGraphQLExecuter`.

  ```
  public class MyDefaultGraphQLExecuter<TSchema> : DefaultGraphQLExecuter<TSchema>
       where TSchema : ISchema
  {

      public MyDefaultGraphQLExecuter(TSchema schema, IDocumentExecuter documentExecuter, IOptions<GraphQLOptions> options, IEnumerable<IDocumentExecutionListener> listeners, IEnumerable<IValidationRule> validationRules) 
          : base(schema, documentExecuter, options, listeners, validationRules)
      {
      }

      protected override ExecutionOptions GetOptions(string operationName, string query, Inputs variables, object context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      {
          var options = base.GetOptions(operationName, query, variables, context, cancellationToken);
          options.FieldNameConverter = Schema.FieldNameConverter;
          return options;
      } 
  }
  ```
- Replace built-in `DefaultGraphQLExecuter`

  ```
              services.AddGraphQL(options =>
          {
              options.EnableMetrics = true;
              options.ExposeExceptions = Environment.IsDevelopment();                
              //options.
          })
          .AddWebSockets()
          .AddDataLoader();

          services.AddMvc();

          services.AddTransient(typeof(IGraphQLExecuter<>), typeof(MyDefaultGraphQLExecuter<>));
  ```