# how to use pascal casing instead of camel casing in graphql dotnet

Tags: graphql, graphql-dotnet, pascalcasing

here I have a mutation, as you can see the parameter name is Product with capital P and the field name is CreateProduct with capital C when I execute this mutation from graphical I have to write the name of the field on camel casing and also the name of the parameter, is there a way to configure graphql-dotnet to respect the names as they are written in the code?

```
 const string STR_Product = "Product";
    public Mutations(IProductService ProductService)
    {
        Name = "Mutation";
        Field<ProductType>(
            "CreateProduct",
            arguments: new QueryArguments(
                new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<ProductInputType>> { Name = STR_Product }),
            resolve: context =>
            {
                var ProductInput = context.GetArgument<ProductInput>(STR_Product);
                return ProductService.CreateAsync(ProductInput.Code, ProductInput.Name, ProductInput.Description);
                //return new ProductInputType();
            }
        );


    }
}
```

Comment: [you can see answer here best Option in Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67096446/3400445)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `IFieldNameConverter` to the `ExecutionOptions`.  It defaults to using `CamelCaseFieldNameConverter`.

Some special considerations are needed for the Introspection types, as those are required to be camel case according to the GraphQL Specification.

GraphQL.NET provides `CamelCaseFieldNameConverter`, `PascalCaseFieldNameConverter`, and `DefaultFieldNameConverter`.  You could also write your own.  [Source found here](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/blob/144d81214c4ae3aa5a506afa77a8f22e288460a5/src/GraphQL/Conversion/IFieldNameConverter.cs).

```
using System;
using GraphQL;
using GraphQL.Types;

public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var schema = Schema.For(@"
      type Query {
        Hello: String
      }
    ");

    var json = schema.Execute(_ =>
    {
      _.Query = "{ Hello }";
      _.Root = new { Hello = "Hello World!" };
      _.FieldNameConverter = new DefaultFieldNameConverter();
    });

    Console.WriteLine(json);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is for the server.  The server defines what fields are available.  See the intro docs for this syntax.  https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/introduction

Comment: schema.Execute is just an extension method that wraps `DocumentExecuter` and `DocumentWriter`.  https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/blob/144d81214c4ae3aa5a506afa77a8f22e288460a5/src/GraphQL/SchemaExtensions.cs

Answer (score 1):

See the above answer by Joe McBride, but instead of "FieldNameConverter" should be using "NameConverter". Example:

```
var json = schema.Execute(_ =>
    {
      _.NameConverter = new DefaultNameConverter(); //or PascalNameConverter, etc.
    });
```

*(posted as an answer because I am unable to comment)*